# Executing simulations smoothly in Unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I have multiple functions (for simulations & they're not ran at the same time, but one is ran at a time), each has high execution time (very likely a few seconds at least, to a few minutes). I know this is not suitable for Unity, a game engine, which favors multiple short functions that ran smooth and quick than a excruciatingly long one.

Basically, as I understand, <strike>when a function gets called in an event, Unity will reduce the FPS to fit the function into the frame it runs on</strike> when a function gets called in an event, the more time it takes, the lower the FPS (some doc on [order of execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)). For example, if function `Foo()` takes one second to run, the FPS lowers to 1 (probably much more, we're ignoring other scripts).

So what can I do to:

1. Keep the long functions running fast (due to lots of heavy calculations, even brute-forcing)

while

2. Have other scripts (UI, etc...) running normally?

The most viable options I've thought of is threading to separate calculations out or something similar.

Comment: What long running methods are we talking about here? In general: put them on background `Task` or `Thread` (you can also look into Unity's Job System) and let the main thread continue rendering while you wait for the result .. the exact solution depends a lot on your use case ...

Comment: `Unity will reduce the FPS to fit the function into the frame it runs on` ... that's formulated a bit funny ^^ Unity does nothing like that ... it's the other way round ... Unity is single threaded and the more stuff is done within one frame, well, the less of such frames can fit within one second

Comment: @derHugo yeah, I really don't know how to formulate that FPS sentence,  it's a bit weirdly worded I think, I'm just throwing in my observation looking at stats.

Comment: @derHugo And for the first question, they're mostly algorithmic functions, dynamic programming at best, brute-forcing (using backtracking)  at worst. I'm trying to do something like a time-comparison. Use Unity for visuals and also I'm familiar with it.

Comment: So yeah I don't really understand where exactly you are going with the question since I think you already answered yourself: Do not execute long taking things in the Unity main thread otherwise it will freeze your app until it is done. Rather execute that stuff asynchronous either using e.g. `Task` or `Thread` or as said Unity's Job System depending on your exact use case and its requirements